# kernel offset: 0x37200000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-- [ end Kernel panic - not synching: No working init found

Tags: boot, kernel, xubuntu

I am using a Hewlett-Packard HP Elitebook 820 G1/1991, BIOS L71 Version. 01.49 02/24/2020 and installed xubuntu 22.04

The boot log journal (only errors indicated with red are included here:

```
    Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
     Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-2)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x7fc02 SErr 0x440001 action 0x0
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x44000001
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1: SError: { RecovData CommWake Handshk }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/20:08:18:93:9e/00:00:1b:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq dma 16384 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/80:50:f8:38:10/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 65536 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/80:58:00:18:50/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 65536 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/20:60:00:18:90/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq dma 16384 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/80:68:00:18:d0/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 65536 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/80:70:00:18:10/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 65536 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/28:78:00:18:50/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 20480 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/10:80:70:18:50/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 8192 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/80:88:00:18:90/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 65536 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/80:90:00:18:d0/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 65536 in
                                               res 41/04:00:f8:38:10/00:00:1b:00:00/60 Emask 0x1 (device error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 463377176 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1063160 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x83700 phys_seg 16 prio class 0
Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 5249024 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x83700 phys_seg 16 prio class 0
Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 9443328 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x83700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
 Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 13637632 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x83700 phys_seg 16 prio class 0
Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 17831936 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x83700 phys_seg 16 prio class 0
Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 22026240 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x83700 phys_seg 5 prio class 0
 Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x18000 SErr 0x450100 action 0x6 frozen
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1: SError: { UnrecovData PHYRdyChg CommWake Handshk }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/08:78:00:18:10/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 4096 out
                                               res 40/00:84:78:73:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/20:80:78:73:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 16384 in
                                               res 40/00:84:78:73:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:11:59 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x40 SErr 0x450101 action 0x6 frozen
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1: SError: { RecovData UnrecovData PHYRdyChg CommWake Handshk }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/08:30:00:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 4096 out
                                               res 40/00:34:00:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
 Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x7e00 SErr 0x410100 action 0x6 frozen
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1: SError: { UnrecovData PHYRdyChg Handshk }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/00:48:68:3e:d1/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 131072 in
                                               res 40/00:5c:00:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/60:50:a0:68:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 49152 in
                                               res 40/00:5c:00:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/08:58:00:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 4096 out
                                               res 40/00:5c:00:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/00:60:80:7a:0c/01:00:04:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq dma 131072 in
                                               res 40/00:5c:00:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:68:f0:26:51/00:00:12:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 4096 in
                                               res 40/00:5c:00:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/00:70:00:18:0c/01:00:1d:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 131072 in
                                               res 40/00:5c:00:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x803ce020 SErr 0x440100 action 0x6 frozen
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1: SError: { UnrecovData CommWake Handshk }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/00:28:b8:3a:d1/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq dma 131072 in
                                               res 40/00:fc:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/c0:68:10:30:50/00:00:12:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 98304 in
                                               res 40/00:fc:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:70:d0:30:50/00:00:12:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 4096 in
                                               res 40/00:fc:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/30:78:d8:30:50/00:00:12:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 24576 in
                                               res 40/00:fc:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:90:08:18:0c/00:00:1d:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 4096 in
                                               res 40/00:fc:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:98:08:18:d4/00:00:0e:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 12288 out
                                               res 40/00:fc:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:a0:a0:68:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 4096 in
                                               res 40/00:fc:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/00:a8:d8:73:0c/01:00:04:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq dma 131072 in
                                               res 40/00:fc:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:f8:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 31 ncq dma 4096 in
                                               res 40/00:fc:08:7b:0c/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
        Oct 05 14:12:01 ebook kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Oct 05 14:23:31 ebook systemd[3836]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/friendly-recovery failed with exit status 1.
```

I have tried the following:

Update grub, update initramfs, reinstalled OS. I am quite new to linux, so I am not sure how to fix this. If anybody could help with some advise it would be grately appreciated.

Comment: You have many hard drive errors in this post. The drive is dead or dying.